# Wifi is slow and disconnects all the time while LAN works fine

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, google-chrome, wireless-router

I have a problem with my Asus UX303LA Notebook that runs Windows 10. The internet is really slow when connected via wifi, sometimes with page load times of 30 seconds in Chrome where it seems to wait around at statuses like "Establishing secure connection", "Resolving Host" and "Waiting for [domain]". I also get ERR_NETWORK_CHANGE (and something other error pages) all the time where I have to refresh and then it usually works 2nd try. This usually happens during the initialization of trivial pages with barely any data (e.g. Google searches) - as soon as a page has loaded and something like a video stream has started, it usually works fine and has no problem to keep loading the stream. There are periods of a few minutes where everything works swimmingly, but most of the time I have the described problems and it seems to have been getting worse for months now. Recently, my wifi started to disconnect once every few minutes (cannot be explained by bad signal as it happens right next to the router) only to reconnect after about 10 seconds. And while I was typing this message, I received a blue screen for the first time: "driver_irql_not_less_or_equal" because of the tcpip.sys driver. What the hell? :-)

I'm pretty sure it is a problem with Windows 10 and its wifi drivers, for the following reasons:

- Everything works perfectly when I'm connected via LAN cable.
- It does not matter which browser I use (I'm normally using Chrome, but I tested other browser with the same issues), so it shouldn't be browser-related.
- Other devices have no problems in our wifi network, so it shouldn't be the router's wifi configuration.

I have completed all the steps [here](http://troubleshooter.xyz/wiki/fix-err_network_changed-in-chrome/) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10741/windows-10-fix-network-connection-issues) with no success. Has anyone any ideas? The last thing I can think of is installing Linux. ;-) Could it possibly be a hardware-related problem? If you need some log or config files for more insight, let me know how they're called and I will try to provide them! Thanks!

Comment: Your really not giving us much usable information, but does WiFi work fine on other devices in the same band? What router or AP? What encryption and band? What WiFi chipset and driver in the Asus? Does the laptop work on other WiFi networks m

Answer (score 0):

I now can answer my own question - reading through a suggested other question on superuser gave me a new idea and I now have a new theory what was going on:

My wifi signal gets quite a bit of interference with all the other wifis in our building. I was aware of that already, but apparently my other devices (MacBook, Android phones) just had less of a problem with that compared to my Windows 10 laptop, so at first I thought it wasn't the reason. Now that I changed the wifi configuration, I'm sure it *was* the reason. Here's what I did:

First I analyzed what networks my neighbors are using with the Android app "Wifi Analyzer". Most of them run 2.4 GHz networks, but because the 5 GHz network barely reaches the other side of my apartment, I tried to stay at 2.4 GHz first and changed the channel to the least crowded one recommended by the app (1). I also set the channel width to 20 MHz (the lowest width) to minimize interference with other signals. Unfortunately, that didn't really help and it was still pretty slow because even this channel is still farely crowded, so I switched to 5 GHz which almost noone in my area is using. I also changed the channel setting from "Auto" to a specific one (just to have more control in which channel the router is) and increased the channel width to 80 MHz. Apparently the latter is generally not recommended as it makes the network more vulnerable to interferences, however with almost no other 5 GHz networks around I thought it might help to give it a bit more throughput at the other side of the apartment where the 5 GHz signal gets weak. This might be wrong and unrelated, so feel free to correct me, but all I know is that with this setup the internet is now super fast in close proximity to the router (no more interference) and also reaches the other side of the apartment okay (didn't work when I tried it with channel width "Auto" a few months back).

I hope this helps some other non-expert like me who runs into a similar problem.

PS: As I now learned, being very close to the router with your laptop showing "perfect signal" does not mean anything in case of interference (as I suggested in my question). The connection will still be unstable.

Comment: General rule of thumb for rf communication. The higher the frequency the more the signal with attenuate with distance/obstacles. Right next to the router, your neighbors wifi signal shouldn't be strong enough to over power your signal. This makes me believe that something else is going on. Like your wireless chipset is overheating. Regards,

Comment: Hmm, is overheating consistent with being less of a problem using a 5 GHz connection compared to 2.4? Because it definitely works much better after my changes. Is there a diagnostics software to specifically check for the temperature of the wireless chipset? Or anything else I can do to verify that?

Comment: I've seen it before yes. It's because in alot of these devices they have two separate physical radios (wifi chipset). I've seen it in reverse also where the 2.4 radio was fine and the 5ghz would drop out after 5 - 15 mins of use. Almost everytime it was a heat issue, or the radio was on it's way out

Comment: Oh, so you are refering to the chipset of the router, not the one in the laptop?